# parsing strings of text numbers and commas in python

Tags: python, list, parsing

hey guys was wondering if someone could offer some quick help. I need to know how to parse some info about certain countries and place them into a list. the list part is easy obviously but the setup of the strings is giving me trouble. This is what an example looks like:

```
Algeria \t919,590\t34,178,188\n
```

well if i do readlineS thats what it would look like in eclipse output, though if i do readlinE it would look like this:

```
Albania     11,100  3,639,453
```

those are just two examples of diff countries and my goal is to make it something like:

```
[Albania, 11,100 , 3,639,453]
```

or maybe just

```
[Albania, 11100 , 3639453]
```

whatever is easier!
thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use the `csv` module to parse your CSV file:

```
import csv

with open('filename.csv', 'r') as handle:
    reader = csv.reader(handle, delimiter='\t')

    for name, number1, number2 in reader:
        print name, number1, number2
```

To parse the numbers, you can strip out the commas:

```
>>> int('123,456,789'.replace(',', ''))
123456789
```

Comment: its just a text file does that make a difference?

Comment: @erp: Nope, CSV files are text files. Yours uses tabs as the delimiters.

Comment: Any idea how to make this error go away "ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)" there are only 3 things in each line of txt in my file and its saying that its getting more than 3 o guess? OH is it because the \n at the end? so could i make delimiter \t or \n?

Comment: @erp: replace `name, number1, number2` with `row` and print out the row.